# React native element type is invalid expected a string

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I am new to React Native and I want to use [react-native-material-bottom-navigation](https://github.com/timomeh/react-native-material-bottom-navigation). I had find some other questions related to this but can't shed some light for me.

I installed the dependency using **npm** and run the command **react-native link** then I executed **react-native run-android**

Here is my code in **App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import BottomNavigation, {
  FullTab
} from 'react-native-material-bottom-navigation'
import {
  View,
  Icon
  } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
  tabs = [
    {
      key: 'games',
      icon: 'gamepad-variant',
      label: 'Games',
      barColor: '#388E3C',
      pressColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.16)'
    },
    {
      key: 'movies-tv',
      icon: 'movie',
      label: 'Movies & TV',
      barColor: '#B71C1C',
      pressColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.16)'
    },
    {
      key: 'music',
      icon: 'music-note',
      label: 'Music',
      barColor: '#E64A19',
      pressColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.16)'
    }
  ]

  renderIcon = icon => ({ isActive }) => (
    <Icon size={24} color="white" name={icon} />
  )

  renderTab = ({ tab, isActive }) => (
    <FullTab
      isActive={isActive}
      key={tab.key}
      label={tab.label}
      renderIcon={this.renderIcon(tab.icon)}
    />
  )

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          {/* Your screen contents depending on current tab. */}
        </View>
        <BottomNavigation
          onTabPress={newTab => this.setState({ activeTab: newTab.key })}
          renderTab={this.renderTab}
          tabs={this.tabs}
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Here's my environment setup

```
Environment:
  OS: Linux 4.13
  Node: 8.11.3
  Yarn: 1.9.4
  npm: 5.6.0
  Watchman: Not Found
  Xcode: N/A
  Android Studio: Not Found

Packages: (wanted => installed)
  react: 16.3.1 => 16.3.1
  react-native: 0.55.4 => 0.55.4
```

Appreciate if someone could help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem like this:-

Even for react native 0.60, you have to link vector icons library to react native like this

```
react-native link react-native-vector-icons
```

Link to React native vector icons library
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-vector-icons#bundled-icon-sets

There are lot of Icon bundle available, and you can import any of them like given below. choose anyone as you like

```
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
```

or

```
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
```

Example

```
      <Icon
        style={{ paddingLeft: 10 }}
        onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}
        name="md-menu"
        size={30}
      />
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `Icon` component in **react-native**

You need to import it from `react-native-vector-icons` or another such library that uses it under the hood.

Check the [library](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons) for more examples

Comment: Then I Import it like this? `import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons'`

Comment: First checkout installation instructions for the library since you need to link it manually, then import it as `import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';`, whichever `icon family` you want to use.

Comment: still had some error. `Invariant violation: Element type is invalid... Check the render method of App`

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker `import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';` as per the documentation

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons#basic-example

Answer (score 0):

you need to install react-native-vector-icons..
go to your cmd or using the terminal and jump to your project path..
do

```
npm install --save react-native-vector-icons
```

and in your project you should import

```
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons'
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

In my case i changed:

```
import { Icon } from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';
```

to

```
import  Icon  from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';
```

and it worked